# Building Isabelle on Linux ARM

Tags: isabelle

has anyone tried to build Isabelle on Linux ARM?
I have Fedora 21 on armv7hl.
I was able to build Pure, but not HOL.
It seems that is a matter of memory, but I am not sure.
Is there a way to build it step-by-step?
the contents of heaps/polyml-5.5.2_armv7l-linux contains only Pure after build.

**Update:**

ARM board is

> Lenovo IdeaPadA10  with 1GB RAM
>   Android version 4.2.2
>   kernel 3.0.36
>   Fedora 21 is installed using chroot

the error message is:

```
* * * Failed to load theory "Inductive" (unresolved "Complete_Lattices")
* * * Failed to load theory "Product_Type" (unresolved "Inductive")
* * * Failed to load theory "Sum_Type" (unresolved "Inductive")
* * * Failed to load theory "Complete_Partial_Order" (unresolved "Product_Type")
* * * Failed to load theory "Nat" (unresolved "Inductive")
* * * Failed to load theory "Datatype" (unresolved "Nat", "Product_Type", "Sum_Type")
* * * Failed to load theory "Finite_Set" (unresolved "Nat", "Product_Type", "Sum_Type")
* * * Failed to load theory "Meson" (unresolved "Nat")
* * * Failed to load theory "ATP" (unresolved "Meson")
* * * Failed to load theory "Metis" (unresolved "ATP")
* * * Failed to load theory "Groups_Big" (unresolved "Finite_Set")
* * * Failed to load theory "Relation" (unresolved "Finite_Set")
* * * Failed to load theory "Transitive_Closure" (unresolved "Relation")
* * * Failed to load theory "Wellfounded" (unresolved "Transitive_Closure")
* * * Failed to load theory "Fun_Def_Base" (unresolved "Wellfounded")
* * * Failed to load theory "Wfrec" (unresolved "Wellfounded")
* * * Failed to load theory "Order_Relation" (unresolved "Wfrec")
* * * Failed to load theory "Equiv_Relations" (unresolved "Groups_Big", "Relation")
* * * Failed to load theory "Hilbert_Choice" (unresolved "Nat", "Wellfounded")
* * * Failed to load theory "BNF_Wellorder_Relation" (unresolved "Order_Relation")
* * * Failed to load theory "BNF_Wellorder_Embedding" (unresolved "BNF_Wellorder_Relation", "Hilbert_Choice")
* * * Failed to load theory "BNF_Constructions_on_Wellorders" (unresolved "BNF_Wellorder_Embedding")
* * * Failed to load theory "Zorn" (unresolved "Hilbert_Choice", "Order_Relation")
* * * Failed to load theory "BNF_Cardinal_Order_Relation" (unresolved "BNF_Constructions_on_Wellorders", "Zorn")
* * * Failed to load theory "BNF_Cardinal_Arithmetic" (unresolved "BNF_Cardinal_Order_Relation")
* * * Failed to load theory "BNF_Def" (unresolved "BNF_Cardinal_Arithmetic", "Fun_Def_Base")
* * * Failed to load theory "BNF_Comp" (unresolved "BNF_Def")
* * * Failed to load theory "Basic_BNFs" (unresolved "BNF_Def")
* * * Failed to load theory "BNF_FP_Base" (unresolved "BNF_Comp", "Basic_BNFs")
* * * Failed to load theory "BNF_LFP" (unresolved "BNF_FP_Base")
* * * Failed to load theory "Num" (unresolved "BNF_LFP", "Datatype")
* * * Failed to load theory "Power" (unresolved "Equiv_Relations", "Num")
* * * Failed to load theory "Option" (unresolved "BNF_LFP", "Datatype", "Finite_Set")
* * * Failed to load theory "Extraction" (unresolved "Datatype", "Option")
* * * Failed to load theory "Lattices_Big" (unresolved "Finite_Set", "Option")
* * * Failed to load theory "Partial_Function" (unresolved "Complete_Partial_Order", "Fun_Def_Base", "Option")
* * * Failed to load theory "Transfer" (unresolved "BNF_FP_Base", "Hilbert_Choice", "Metis", "Option")
* * * Failed to load theory "Fun_Def" (unresolved "Partial_Function")
* * * Failed to load theory "Lifting" (unresolved "Equiv_Relations", "Transfer")
* * * Failed to load theory "Lifting_Option" (unresolved "Lifting", "Option")
* * * Failed to load theory "Lifting_Product" (unresolved "Basic_BNFs", "Lifting")
* * * Failed to load theory "Lifting_Set" (unresolved "Lifting")
* * * Failed to load theory "Lifting_Sum" (unresolved "Basic_BNFs", "Lifting")
* * * Failed to load theory "Quotient" (unresolved "Lifting")
* * * Failed to load theory "Int" (unresolved "Equiv_Relations", "Fun_Def", "Power", "Quotient")
* * * Failed to load theory "Nat_Transfer" (unresolved "Int")
* * * Failed to load theory "Divides" (unresolved "Nat_Transfer")
* * * Failed to load theory "Set_Interval" (unresolved "Lattices_Big", "Nat_Transfer")
* * * Failed to load theory "Numeral_Simprocs" (unresolved "Divides")
* * * Failed to load theory "Code_Numeral" (unresolved "Divides", "Lifting", "Nat_Transfer")
* * * Failed to load theory "SMT2" (unresolved "Divides")
* * * Failed to load theory "Semiring_Normalization" (unresolved "Nat_Transfer", "Numeral_Simprocs")
* * * Failed to load theory "Groebner_Basis" (unresolved "Semiring_Normalization")
* * * Failed to load theory "Presburger" (unresolved "Groebner_Basis", "Set_Interval")
* * * Failed to load theory "Sledgehammer" (unresolved "Presburger", "SMT2")
* * * Failed to load theory "List" (unresolved "Code_Numeral", "Lifting_Option", "Lifting_Product", "Lifting_Set", "Sledgehammer")
* * * Failed to load theory "Map" (unresolved "List")
* * * Failed to load theory "Random" (unresolved "List")
* * * Failed to load theory "Enum" (unresolved "Map")
* * * Failed to load theory "String" (unresolved "Enum")
* * * Failed to load theory "BNF_GFP" (unresolved "BNF_FP_Base", "String")
* * * Failed to load theory "Predicate" (unresolved "String")
* * * Failed to load theory "Lazy_Sequence" (unresolved "Predicate")
* * * Failed to load theory "Typerep" (unresolved "String")
* * * Failed to load theory "Limited_Sequence" (unresolved "Lazy_Sequence")
* * * Failed to load theory "Code_Evaluation" (unresolved "Limited_Sequence", "Typerep")
* * * Failed to load theory "Quickcheck_Random" (unresolved "Code_Evaluation", "Enum", "Random")
* * * Failed to load theory "Quickcheck_Exhaustive" (unresolved "Quickcheck_Random")
* * * Failed to load theory "Quickcheck_Narrowing" (unresolved "Quickcheck_Random")
* * * Failed to load theory "Record" (unresolved "Quickcheck_Exhaustive")
* * * Failed to load theory "Random_Pred" (unresolved "Quickcheck_Random")
* * * Failed to load theory "Random_Sequence" (unresolved "Random_Pred")
* * * Failed to load theory "Nitpick" (unresolved "Record")
* * * Failed to load theory "SMT" (unresolved "Record")
* * * Failed to load theory "Predicate_Compile" (unresolved "Quickcheck_Exhaustive", "Random_Sequence")
* * * Failed to load theory "Main" (unresolved "BNF_GFP", "Extraction", "Lifting_Sum", "Nitpick", "Predicate_Compile", "Quickcheck_Narrowing", "SMT")
* * * Failed to load theory "Archimedean_Field" (unresolved "Main")
* * * Failed to load theory "Conditionally_Complete_Lattices" (unresolved "Main")
* * * Failed to load theory "Fact" (unresolved "Main")
* * * Failed to load theory "Parity" (unresolved "Main")
* * * Failed to load theory "GCD" (unresolved "Fact", "Parity")
* * * Failed to load theory "Topological_Spaces" (unresolved "Conditionally_Complete_Lattices", "Main")
* * * Failed to load theory "Rat" (unresolved "Archimedean_Field", "GCD")
* * * Failed to load theory "Real" (unresolved "Conditionally_Complete_Lattices", "Rat")
* * * Failed to load theory "Real_Vector_Spaces" (unresolved "Real", "Topological_Spaces")
* * * Failed to load theory "Limits" (unresolved "Real_Vector_Spaces")
* * * Failed to load theory "Deriv" (unresolved "Limits")
* * * Failed to load theory "Series" (unresolved "Limits")
* * * Failed to load theory "NthRoot" (unresolved "Deriv", "Parity")
* * * Failed to load theory "Transcendental" (unresolved "Deriv", "Fact", "NthRoot", "Series")
* * * Failed to load theory "Complex" (unresolved "Transcendental")
* * * Failed to load theory "MacLaurin" (unresolved "Transcendental")
* * * Failed to load theory "Taylor" (unresolved "MacLaurin")
* * * Failed to load theory "Complex_Main" (unresolved "Complex", "Deriv", "Main", "Real", "Taylor", "Transcendental")
* * * Outer syntax error (line 984 of "~~/src/HOL/Complete_Lattices.thy"): keyword ")" expected,
* * * but identifier output (line 984 of "~~/src/HOL/Complete_Lattices.thy") was found
* * * At command "<malformed>" (line 984 of "~~/src/HOL/Complete_Lattices.thy")
```

Comment: Which ARM board is it and how much memory does it have?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? What's written in the log file?

Comment: Where from did you obtain the Isabelle distribution you are using? And how exactly did you try to build it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the ARM platform -- in recent years all system integration efforts of Isabelle were standardized towards x86/x86_64.  Note that Poly/ML is only interpreted on ARM, so it will be a bit slow.

Moreover, for full Isabelle/HOL, which is a really huge thing, you do need a bit more than just 1GB.  I usually take 4GB as the bottom line, although 2GB might work for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I did recently managed to build Isabelle/HOL and use Isabelle/jEdit on an old Dell Inspiron laptop with a single-core 1.6 GHz Celeron and 512 MB RAM (perhaps it was 1 GB, I don't remember exactly). But it was probably swapping heavily, so at the very least, you will require a GB or two of swap.